# how to Vectorize the np.linalg.norm between to matices for each row

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, normalization

I am trying to optimize my code and for the following example arrays,(that can be dynamic in length):

```
arr1 = np.random.random(300).reshape((-1,3))
arr2 = np.random.random(450).reshape((-1,3))

>>> arr1 

array([[0.32725109, 0.39912246, 0.9834273 ],
        [0.78003681, 0.92057381, 0.06478441],
        [0.15232456, 0.82258548, 0.1685084 ],
        ...
        [0.10011657, 0.05840116, 0.07685251],
        [0.360477  , 0.09061205, 0.54737966],
        [0.44562439, 0.90453774, 0.27240101]])
```

The following code are the critical part:

```
result_arr = np.zeros((arr1.shape[0],arr2.shape[0]))
for arr1_index,arr1_row in enumerate(arr1):
    for arr2_index, arr2_row in enumerate(arr2):
        result_arr[arr1_index,arr2_index] = 1/(1+np.linalg.norm(arr1_row - arr2_row,2) ** (1/3) )
```

and the performance is too poor, is there any idea of how do I turn this `np.linalg.norm` function to work on a vectorized way and and to skip this use of loops. there is also arithmetics to take into account here and I can get my head over it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use broadcasting and exploit the vectorized nature of the `linalg.norm` function to perform the operation in one function call as follow (in my computer this achieves 2 orders of magnitude of improvement in speed):

```
import numpy as np
# Create dummy arrays
arr1 = np.random.random(300).reshape((-1,3))
arr2 = np.random.random(450).reshape((-1,3))
# Output
r = 1 / (1 + np.linalg.norm(arr1[:,None] - arr2, axis=-1)**(1/3))
```

I suspect further improvements could be obtained via NumPy's [`einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy-einsum) function.

Comment: can you explain the axis = -1?

Comment: @adirabargil axis=-1 means along the last axis. @Lith: The ```**(1/3)``` could be further optimized (and would be more precise) with np.cbrt

Comment: can you write it down homer?

Comment: is there a chance to do it without broadcasting the array?

Comment: @adirabargil Of course, but in that case one loop will be necessary and speed will drop accordingly.

Comment: are you sure there isnt a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, broadcasting is what allow us to do the calculation in one call in the first place. Otherwise dimensions won't match. What is the problem in using broadcasting?